# PHP include path is not using the path specified in php.ini

Tags: php, apache

I have a php script that includes a few files but cannot find them in the include path I have specified in my php.ini file.

I am running apache with this command:

```
php -S localhost:<portnumber> -c php.ini
```

In the php.ini file I specify paths

```
include_path=".:/usr/local/php/lib:<another path>:<another path>"
```

Then when I run the php script I get an error

```
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'ExceptionHandler.php'
(include_path='.:<some path different from ini>')
```

It seems that the server configuration is using a different path than the one I have specified. How can I get the right include paths?

Answer (score 0):

are u sure you have ExceptionHandler.php in your local directory?
for the error message: it says you do not have the file that you want to include.

Guess when you run:

```
php -S localhost:<portnumber> -c php.ini
```

the script is trying to find the ExceptionHandler.php in current working directory, but your ExceptionHandler.php is in your $HOME

Comment: I have the ExceptionHandler.php file in a local includes directory

Comment: No its in ~/myProject/

Comment: can u show me the require line for ExceptionHandler.php?

Comment: 'require(ExceptionHandler.php)'